# C Program to Calculate Hypotenuse

Tags: c, function, hypotenuse

I'm fairly new to coding and am currently learning C. In class I was given an assignment to write a program that calculates the hypotenuse of the triangle by using our own functions. However, there seems to be something wrong with the code that I have written.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double hypotenuse(double x, double y, double z);

int main(void) {
    double side1, side2, side3, counter;

    side3 = 1;

    for (counter = 0; counter <= 2; counter++) {
        printf("Enter values for two sides: ");
        scanf_s("%d %d", &side1, &side2);

        printf("%.2f\n", hypotenuse(side1, side2, side3));
    }

    return 0;
}

double hypotenuse(double x, double y, double z) {
    x *= x;
    y *= y;
    z = sqrt(x + y);

    return z;
}
```

My instructor said that we're allowed to use the square root function `sqrt` of the math library. The main errors that I'm facing are:

1) `side3` is not defined (This is why I just arbitrarily set it to 1, but is there some other way to prevent this error from happening?)
2) If I, for example, inputted 3 and 4 as `side1` and `side2`, then `side3` should be 5. However, the printed result is an absurdly long number.

Thank you for the help! Any words of advice are appreciated.

Comment: The code you've posted will not result in "side3 not defined".

Comment: "result is an absurdly long number" - what is the result?

Comment: `"%d %d"` --> `"%lf %lf"` (Also `printf("%.2f\n", side3 = hypotenuse(side1, side2, side3));`)

Comment: 130899030500194208680850288727868915862901750748094271410143232.00 This is the number. I have no idea where it came from.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Certainly `scanf_s("%d %d", &side1, &side2);` should generate a compiler warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need side3 variable - it is not used in calculation. And you function `hypotenuse` returns the result, so you can directly output the result of `sqrt`.

Answer (score 3):

I use Ubuntu Linux and write it this way. Please look if you like it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double hypotenuse(double x, double y) {
    double z = sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    return z;
}

int main(void) {
    double b1, b2, counter;
    for (counter = 0; counter <= 2; counter++) {
        printf("Enter values for two sides: ");
        scanf("%lf %lf", &b1, &b2);
        printf("%.2f\n", hypotenuse(b1, b2));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Test

```
$ ./a.out 
Enter values for two sides: 1 1.73
2.00
```

Answer (score 2):

OP's code has some problems:

Key problem: Code should have generated a compiler warning as `scanf()` is directed to treat `&side1` as an `int *`.  Turn on all compiler warnings to save you time.  Code used `"%d"` rather than the matching `"%lf"` to read a `double`.  Also the return value should be checked to validate input.

```
double side1, side2, side3, counter;
...
// scanf_s("%d %d", &side1, &side2);
if (scanf_s("%lf %lf", &side1, &side2) != 2) puts("Input error");
```

---

`size3` is not needed.  Call `hypotenuse()` with 2 arguments. [@ghostprgmr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43293237/2410359)

```
// printf("%.2f\n", hypotenuse(side1, side2, side3));
printf("%.2f\n", hypotenuse(side1, side2));

// double hypotenuse(double x, double y, double z) {
double hypotenuse(double x, double y) {
   double z = ...
```

---

Minor: Code used `"%.2f"` to print the value of the hypotenuse.  This may be OK with select input values to OP's code, but is a poor choice, in general.  If input values are vary small like 0.001 and 0.002, the output will print rounded value of 0.00.  With very large values, the result will show many non-important digits as OP found with `130899030500194208680850288727868915862901750748094271410143‌​232.00`.

For development and debugging, consider using `"%e"` ,`"%g"` or `"%a"` to see a relevant `double`.

---

Note that `x * x + y * y` is prone to over/under flow, even when *mathematically* `sqrt(x * x + y * y)` is in the `double` range.  That is one advantage of the standard function `hypot(x,y)` as it usually handles those edge cases well.

Answer (score 1):

As a reference for anyone viewing this question:

You don't *need* to write your own function. Standard C provides [functions to calculate the hypotnuse](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.7.3):

> **7.12.7.3  The `hypot` functions**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <math.h>
> double hypot(double x, double y);
> float hypotf(float x, float y);
> long double hypotl(long double x, long double y);
> ```

Note that you likely need to link with `-lm`, though that's not listed explicitly in the function documentation in the C standard nor [the latest POSIX documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/hypot.html).  It might be documented elsewhere in the standards.

([Link to C11 [draft] standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) - likely to be much longer-lived.)

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I am aware that there are library functions built into almost every programming language. However, I'm still a beginner so the professor wanted us to try and write our own functions to get a grasp of what it's like. Thank you again!

Comment: @Sean I added it so anyone looking to calculate the value of a hypotnuse - but who doesn't care if it's done with a library function - can see that there's a standard function to do so.  Someone who doesn't know that there are functions to do this might not even know where to begin looking.  There's way too much documentation written that pretty much requires almost knowing the answer before you can find it.

Answer (score 1):

Use correct format specifiers!
Format Specifier for double is not %d! Rest is fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double hypotenuse(double x, double y, double z);

int main(void) {
    double side1, side2, side3, counter;

    side3 = 1;

    for (counter = 0; counter <= 2; counter++) {
        printf("Enter values for two sides: ");
        scanf("%lf %lf", &side1, &side2);

        printf("%.2f\n", hypotenuse(side1, side2, side3));
    }

    return 0;
}

double hypotenuse(double x, double y, double z) {
    x *= x;
    y *= y;
    z = sqrt(x + y);

    return z;
}
```

Also you could modify it to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double hypotenuse(double x, double y);

int main(void) {
    double side1, side2, counter;



    for (counter = 0; counter <= 2; counter++) {
        printf("Enter values for two sides: ");
        scanf("%lf %lf", &side1, &side2);

        printf("%.2f\n", hypotenuse(side1, side2));
    }

    return 0;
}

double hypotenuse(double x, double y) {
    x *= x;
    y *= y;
    return sqrt(x + y);


}
```